# Please fix the spelling of the "seychelles" tag

Tags: support, status-completed, tagging, editing

There was a Seychelles tag created with the misspelling of [seichelles](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/seichelles).

While I have recommended a wiki/excerpt, could someone please correct the spelling?

Comment: I asked mods in the chat not too long ago. Well done for posting it here on Meta. Yes, t'was me who misspelled the tag.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see @mindcorrosive did this already :) Thanks for flagging it up!

Comment: Can't you (mods) use the [tag:status-completed] tag on this question to mark it as completed?

Comment: @JoErNanO Interesting point. Um, that's typically used by SO employees for questions tagged with [tag:bugs] but I guess we can use it as well.